# Vuejs :class not working as expected in template

Tags: vue.js, binding

The class binding is not working as expected using a template, as the image below shows:

[image]

I have a array with many categories and when the user click it has to filter, this i already did, for whose category he wants. My problem is that once i click in other category, the ones before stills on.

The template receives a array such as:

```
categories: ["todos", "beer", "eco-bag", "paper-bag", "suplementos", "chas", "doces", "chocolates", "dieteticos"]
```

Here is the template:

```
<template id="category-box">
  <span :class="{active: currentFilter == category}" @click="setFilter(category)">
     {{category}}
  </span>
</template>
```

The call inside the #app element:

```
<div id="category">
    <category v-for="category in categories" :category="category"></category>
</div>
```

The code that handles it:

```
const Category = Vue.component("category", {
  template: "#category-box",
  props: {
    "category": String,
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      currentFilter: "todos"
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setFilter: function(filter) {
      this.currentFilter = filter;
      this.$parent.$emit('filteredCategory', filter);
        }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like currentFilter is scoped to the individual Category component.  Each time you set it you are setting it for that component.  Move it to the parent scope so that there is only one currentFilter for all of your categories.

Comment: Thank you! I think using the event bus i could solve that.

Comment: Worked like a charm! I passed the object as a prop and used the v-for directive inside the template.